# Get alphabetical number of characters in string

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Given a string such as `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`, how would I go about returning a list of the alphabetical number of each letter in the string, example being `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1 - First@ToCharacterCode@"a" + ToCharacterCode@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
>   20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26}

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

p = StringPartition[str, 1]
```

> {"a", "b", "c", etc.}

```
ord = Rule @@@ Transpose @ {Alphabet[], Range[Length@Alphabet[]]}
```

> {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, etc.}

```
p /. rule
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
>   20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26}